# How to check whether update succeeded in node.js and sqlite3 ?

Tags: node.js, rest, sqlite

Could anyone give me any advice on how to check whether an update statement has succeeded when using node.js and the sqlite3 package installed from npm install sqlite3 (https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/wiki/API)

To perform an update, I'm doing the following:

```
    var id = req.params.id;
    var thing = req.body;
    stmt = db.prepare("UPDATE FOO set name=?, year=? where id=?");
    stmt.bind(thing.name, thing.year, id);
    stmt.run(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
        } else {
            if (result) {
                console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(wine));
        }
    });
```

However, result is never defined.

If I change stmt.run() to be stmt.all(), I get a result, but it seems to be empty - printing it to the console shows nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `result` is for the records returned from a `SELECT` query.

If the `UPDATE` command fails, you get `err`.

To find out how many records have been updates, see `changes`.

Comment: Hmm - Using the above code, trying to update a row that never exists (so specifying an id that doesn't exist in the database), err is still not defined / populated.

That's why I was looking into the result field, since err was undefined.

Comment: If there is nothing to update, err is still undefined after the above code. However, this.changes inside the function does seem to solve the issue - thanks!

Comment: Side note: an es6 style function will automatically bind to lexical `this`, preventing you from accessing the above `this.changes` in the callback

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue where it returned undefined. I fixed it by changing my method

from:

```
db.run(query, [data.isActive, data.id], (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({'Response':'Error updating user', err });
    } else {
        console.log(`Rows affected: ${this.changes}`)
        res.status(200).send({'Response': 'Success updating'});
    };
});
```

To:

```
db.run(query, [data.isActive, data.id], async function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({'Response':'Error updating user', err });
    } else {
        console.log(`Rows affected: ${this.changes}`)
        res.status(200).send({'Response': 'Success updating'});
    };
});
```

Note the first line, i changed it from an arrow function to an async function.

Comment: 1. Actual code, thanks! 2. `async` is unnecessary (because the function body isn't doing anything asynchronous). The key is to just use a regular function (and *not* an arrow function) due to the need to access `this` within the function.